# wrapping a perl script in bash - echo to IRC bot

Tags: bash, error-handling, execution

I have a perl script - wow.pl. 
I want to write a wrapper that will run the script and if it exits successfully, 
echo a message to the IRC chat windows that listens on port 4514 on foo400host. 
The echo works, but the script does not necessarily run.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ~/scripts/wow.pl ] 
   then 
       echo "wow.pl is done" | /home/bin/nc foo400host 4514
fi
```

Comment: With `[ ~/scripts/wow.pl ]` you are testing that the string `~/scripts/wow.pl` is not empty (which is always true). If you want to test the existence of the file do `[ -f ~/scripts/wow.pl ]`

Comment: actually for some reason - I thought that the "~/scripts/wow.pl" would evaluate to a 0 or a zero and the if statement would run the echo if the script was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return status of your script, you can do this using [`$?`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

```
/usr/bin/perl ~/scripts/wow.pl
rc=$?
if [[ $rc == 0 ]] ; then
   echo "wow.pl is done" | /home/bin/nc foo400host 4514
fi
exit $rc
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line:

```
if [ ~/scripts/wow.pl ]
```

To

```
if ~/scripts/wow.pl
```

`[ ]` is used for conditional expressions and what you're wanting is to test the result of the command itself.